# Google Geocoding returns false address

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to geocode a bunch of zip codes to get their coordinates using the script below.
Since I'm mostly trying to convert German zip codes, I am using the country ISO code as prefix to make sure Google doesn't return US locations.

My data looks as follows:

```
DE-01099
DE-01108
DE-01109
```

These zip codes are near Dresden, Germany. Now, when looking up `DE-01099` i.e. in GoogleMaps, it shows Dresden, as it should. Same thing, when I geocode it (`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=DE-01099`), it returns "Dresden".

Searching for `DE-01108` in GoogleMaps also shows Dresden, as supposed to. However, when geocoding this zip code, it returns `Springfield, MA 01108, USA`, even though I explicitely said `DE-`.

Any idea why / what to do?
Thanks in advance!

---

#### Script

```
import urllib
import sqlite3
import json
import time
import ssl

serviceurl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?"

# Deal with SSL certificate anomalies Python > 2.7
# scontext = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
scontext = None

conn = sqlite3.connect('geodata.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Locations (address TEXT, geodata TEXT)''')

fh = open("where2.data")
for line in fh:
    address = line.strip()
    print ''
    cur.execute("SELECT geodata FROM Locations WHERE address= ?", (buffer(address), ))

#    try:
#        data = cur.fetchone()[0]
#        print "Found in database ",address
#        continue
#    except:
#        pass

    print 'Resolving', address
    url = serviceurl + urllib.urlencode({"sensor":"false", "address": address})
    print 'Retrieving', url
    uh = urllib.urlopen(url, context=scontext)
    data = uh.read()
    print 'Retrieved',len(data),'characters',data[:20].replace('\n',' ')
    try:
        js = json.loads(str(data))
        # print js  # We print in case unicode causes an error
    except:
        continue

    if 'status' not in js or (js['status'] != 'OK' and js['status'] != 'ZERO_RESULTS') :
        print '==== Failure To Retrieve ===='
        print data
        break

    cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Locations (address, geodata)
            VALUES ( ?, ? )''', ( buffer(address),buffer(data) ) )
    conn.commit()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem.  When you visit the api endpoint, the response is in Germany, as you expect.  At what point are you getting Springfield?  Also, this code is Python not Javascript, you might want to update your tags to get a more specific response.

Comment: Oops, mistagged, ha. Changed it, thanks. The script creates an `.sqlite` database in which the json is stored. From there, I read the data. Inside this database, after the script finishing up, it says Dresden for the first zip and Springfield for the latter 2 zips. I do not know why.

Comment: @JordanBurnett I noticed that when opening the [link to geocode 01109](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=DE-01109) it returns a json containing Dresden and then Springfield. In the database, however, it's the other way around: Springfield first, Dresden second.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [component filtering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ComponentFiltering) on your request.  Add `&components=country:DE` to the request rather than appending "DE-" to the zip code:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=01108&components=country:DE
```

returns the one result for Dresden:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "01108",
               "short_name" : "01108",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Weixdorf",
               "short_name" : "Weixdorf",
               "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Dresden",
               "short_name" : "Dresden",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Dresden",
               "short_name" : "DD",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Sachsen",
               "short_name" : "SN",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Germany",
               "short_name" : "DE",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "01108 Dresden, Germany",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 51.17815,
                  "lng" : 13.8371901
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 51.1285391,
                  "lng" : 13.742293
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 51.1443239,
               "lng" : 13.7997057
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 51.17815,
                  "lng" : 13.8371901
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 51.1285391,
                  "lng" : 13.742293
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJedA1NUPMCUcRsJIzlc6xIRw",
         "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This already is my workaround. However, I want to geocode *mostly* German zips, but not only. There's US, Belgium, Sweden, Austria, etc. zips, that need to be geocoded as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that "DE-" prefix in address parameter doesn't apply any strict filter. If you need a strict filter you must use a [component filtering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ComponentFiltering) as suggested by @geocodezip

Your request will have a form

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code%3A01099%7Ccountry%3ADE&key=YOUR_API_KEY

So you say to geocoding service: "please find postal code 01099 in Germany".

Comment: Sure, and I believe that country filter is necessary to resolve ambiguous postal codes. Simple example postal code 32108. You will have '
32108 Bad Salzuflen, Germany', '
Zarasai 32108, Lithuania' and '
Franja Sara Lugo, 32108 Cd Juárez, Chih., Mexico'.

Comment: Right but that doesn't solve anything for me. Looks like I'm gonna have to stick to my workaround